# Appium Studio : Failed to Connect to XCAutomation error coming while opening iOS device after upgrading to iOS 17

Tags: appium, appium-desktop, ios17

I am using Appium Studio community version for iOS automation.When I have upgraded my iPhone to iOS 17.0.1 i am unable to start my device .I am getting error **Unable to Connect to XCAutomation**  while opening iOS device.
I have attached screenshot of error for refrence.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnxd9.png)

I have upgraded Appium Studio to latest version i.e. **23.9.9184** but still getting same error.